# internal error in Code Signing subsystem Xcode 12

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode12, xcframework

I am getting Code signing error while uploading app to App Store, it is working fine in simulator and device, only getting this error while uploading.

[image]

This target of my app is using a framework developed by me, so previously it was giving an error of code signing for the framework, so I did some changes related to code signing and it's gone, but now it is giving same code signing error for my app target.

It was working fine with Xcode 11 (Building and uploading), I did some changes in framework related to build architecture to make it compatible with Xcode 12.

Interestingly the error page says View distribution logs for more information, but the only information I found related to this issue is below,

> Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-06-27/MyApp 27-06-21, 4.26 PM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/MyApp.app/MyApp>’, hardenedRuntime='0'>'> to: /var/folders/k6/jqdbxs4x6_d65495_v9127180000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~v6vq0l/entitlements~~~a8rUuu
> 2021-06-27 10:56:59 +0000  Running /usr/bin/codesign '-vvv' '--force' '--sign' 'A5640AE3DE907C3AC86E500508C5B6A3096D871F' '--entitlements' '/var/folders/k6/jqdbxs4x6_d65495_v9127180000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~v6vq0l/entitlements~~~a8rUuu' '--preserve-metadata=identifier,flags,runtime' '/var/folders/k6/jqdbxs4x6_d65495_v9127180000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~v6vq0l/Root/Payload/MyApp.app'
> 2021-06-27 10:57:00 +0000  /var/folders/k6/jqdbxs4x6_d65495_v9127180000gn/T/XcodeDistPipeline.~~~v6vq0l/Root/Payload/MyApp.app: internal error in Code Signing subsystem
> 2021-06-27 10:57:00 +0000  /usr/bin/codesign exited with 1

Comment: Have you tried **Automatic manage signings**?

Comment: Nope, didn't tried Automatic Signing yet, will try.

Comment: Tried with Automatic manage signing, no luck yet @abhisheksharma

Answer (score 5):

**Fix:** Set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** from Build Settings.

This is clearly Xcode 12 bug, something is mismatched while enable bitcode, I tried uploading build from Xcode 13 beta and uploading was working fine, of course it was rejected by AppStore connect because of beta SDK.

---

If you are using third party framework, make sure you embed Framework, Otherwise you will get crash on launch in release build, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/addressing-missing-framework-crashes) is the detailed missing framework crash solution by Apple.

Comment: You have to open Build Settings, and set Enable Bitcode to NO

Comment: Thanks Man! I almost read each and every thread related to signing. But this is the one which fixed my problem.

Comment: I am glad it helped!